# Python threads making them take 100% of my cpu

Tags: multithreading, python-3.x

**Python threads making them take 100% of my cpu**

All,

How do I make this script take 100% of my cpu?  If this post is bad please explain why! Any help would be much appreciated.

```
import threading
import sys

def isPrime(number):
    # isPrime is to check if a int is Prime
    if not isinstance(number,int):
        #check if number is a int
        raise Exception("Please enter a int. Function: isPrime.")
    #create array of numbers to check
    rangeOfNumbers=range(1,number+1,1)
    #count of how many multiplacations if it is a prime number it would be 2
    multiplicationCount=0
    #tow for loops to loop through all possibilities
    for n1 in rangeOfNumbers:
        for n2 in rangeOfNumbers:
            if (n1*n2==number):
                multiplicationCount +=1
    if (multiplicationCount==2):
        print(number)
        return True
    else:
        return False




if __name__ == "__main__":
    if not sys.version_info[0] == 3:
        raise Exception("Please Upgrade or Downgrade your python to python 3.")
    number=0
    while True:
        threads=[]
        for i in range(100):
            number+=1
            thread=threading.Thread(target=isPrime,args=[number])
            thread.start()
            threads=[]
            threads.append(thread)
        for thread in threads:
            thread.join()
```

Comment: https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock

Comment: Is it just the GIL lock or am i missing something else

Comment: The GIL lock causes only one Python thread to be running at a time (except when doing IO and some other stuff). Use the `multiprocessing` module instead. Also 100 threads is major overkill.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`isPrime` not does no IO or other operation that could potentially relinquish the CPU (except `print`). It therefore consumes 100% of *one* CPU core. Since enough such jobs are kicked of, measurable CPU usage should stay at about 100% of one core. Note that, since Python has the additional limitation that only one thread can execute bytecode at the same time (referred to as the [Global Interpreter Lock](https://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock)), no parallelism is achieved here.

[Look into Python's `multiprocessing` module to achieve real concurrency.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) It spawns off new Python processes, thus allowing multiple primality tests to execute at the same time.

Lastly, your code does not properly wait for all threads

```
while True:
    threads=[]
    for i in range(100):
        number+=1
        thread=threading.Thread(target=isPrime,args=[number])
        thread.start()
        threads=[] # threads being reset here!
        threads.append(thread)
    for thread in threads:
        thread.join()
```

(This is probably not intentional). It means that you keep creating threads in an infinite loop, but only wait for one of them to finish. This is going to run you out of memory at some point. It would be much more catastrophic if Python had real threading, though ...

Comment: Also if i get rid of the print it still would not get my cpu to 100%

Comment: You're saying without the `print` it is only 20%? How many cores do you have?